# Issue launching Julia 1.1.1 desktop shortcut on MacOS?

Tags: julia

I was prompted to allow Julia 1.1.1 to have access to certain things on my computer and accidentally pressed don't allow. Now, when I try to launch the Julia 1.1.1 desktop shortcut, I get the following error:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset this decision by running:

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents
tccutil reset SystemPolicyAllFiles
```

This will reset *all* policies regarding these permissions, prompting you to gain access for all apps previously allowed/denied.  If you don't want to do that, you can try downloading [this utility](https://github.com/jacobsalmela/tccutil) that has more fine-grained control.